# Why use "finir par" instead of "finir de" before an infinitive?

Tags: usage, prépositions

While inspecting some song lyrics, I noticed this sentence:

> J'ai fini **par** te pardonner.
>
> <sup>(*Je te pardonne* chanté par *Maître Gims*)</sup>

I'm confused to see the preposition *par* before an infinitive, because all I've seen in the past is *à* and *de*.

If I were to write that sentence, I would have written it as:

> J'ai fini **de** te pardonner.

with the meaning "I have finally forgiven you".

I feel strongly that *par* is in fact correct, but I have no idea why it's right and why *de* is wrong. Also what is the usage of *par* here?

Comment: Both are correct. *Finir par* means *to end up doing smth*. So the first sentence means "*I ended up forgiving you*" or "*After some time I finally forgave you*"

Comment: about me de iBug aux erreurs: Je suis seulement un étudiant du français et je fais souvent des erreurs.

Comment: Even better: je suis étudiant EN français. And even better than better: j'étudie le français

Comment: Note: There are much better songwriters than Maître Gims if you want to learn French, or, for that matter, listen to good music. ;)

Comment: @EricDuminil Learning French is real, music is only appetite. and I *do* have some more experience in other Romance languages that I suppose may help to some extents

Comment: @EricDuminil Despite, I'd still highly recommend his song *Tu vas me manquer* ([YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KA3Q1duzwaE)).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The meanings are different:

*Finir par* means this is the last action you will take in a process of multiple actions you had to follow, or from multiple options that you had to choose from.

*J'ai fini par te pardonner* means "after coping with other feelings, in the end, I have forgiven you".

You could extend the explanation that way:

> Au début, j'étais tellement fâché que je ne voulais plus te parler, mais j'ai fini par te pardonner.

*Finir de* means the action has been fully completed.
*J'ai fini de te pardonner* sounds a bit weird as *pardonner* is usually not something that you decide to start and that should take you a while to complete, so as to mean "I started forgiving you some time ago, and now I have finished this action and you are forgiven".

Another example with another verb:

> J'ai fini de réparer ma voiture.

means you have completed the action of repairing your car

> J'ai fini par réparer ma voiture.

means you had the option to have it repaired in a garage, or even to not repair it at all, but in the end you decided to repair it yourself.

Comment: Does this equal "finish to" vs "finish with"?

Comment: *J'ai fini de te pardonner* sounds to me as "I'm tired of regularly having to forgive you, so I'll stop doing it".

Comment: @henning Not really. Maybe a closer approach would be "Ended up" like I ended up forgiving you.

Comment: @henning Just noticed the exact same sentence has been given in the OP's post comments. Sorry for the redundancy :)

Comment: @AzirisMorora I didn't spot that, so it's welcome redundancy. :)